# How to disable State/Province in billing address blocks

Tags: billingblock

In the UK, the list of counties provided by Civicrm (and by the ISO) is mysterious to say the least to most UK dwellers. Many people think they live in a county which changed to something else years ago!

So, afaik it's best not to use counties in addresses with drop-down options - such as billing fields.

Therefore, how can one disable state/county in a billing address block? Or at least make it not required?

We use Authorize.net for most UK transactions.

Thanks for your help!

Drupal 7.56, Civi 4.7.22

PS - I see this: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19688
But I don't think it helps in this situation?

Comment: A similar issue was raised at [this reference](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/15793/billing-name-and-address) that might help in your situation.

Comment: Agreed that CRM-19688 isn't relevant to your situation, but I think the link that peterb raises is.

Comment: I've asked a question in the comments of peterb's link. I'm not sure it still applies to 4.7.22? I think I read it that all fields are set to be required in one sweep.

Answer (score 3):

We also needed to disable some billing fields, including the state/province, so we wrote an extension for it: https://github.com/WeMoveEU/nobillingfields

It keeps only first name, last name and zip code, and this is a hardcoded thing, but you should be able to easily adapt to your needs if you have a developer. 
Note however that when we migrated to 4.7, the extension stopped working, and I patched civi core to make it work again. [I reported the problem](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19965), and the suggested fix was to unset validation errors with a hook, but I have yet to try it.

I'm afraid there is no easier solution...

Answer (score 2):

The address fields are defined in a file call CRM/Core/Payment.php.
I approached this by overridding the file in a Custom PHP directory and commenting out the State/province field. Not ideal I realise, but fast.